# presentViewController sends message to deallocated instance error on iPad

Tags: xcode, ipad

I have a collection view controller with a list. I open an item in a new view controller:

```
self.detailController = [_theStoryboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailController"];
//init data
[self presentViewController:_detailController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The modal view loads correctly. However, if I close this view and open another item, I get the error:

```
*** -[DetailViewController isKindOfClass:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xb3e2200
```

Through debugging, I've nslog'ed the viewcontrollers:

```
NSLog(@"controller:%@", _detailController);
[self presentViewController:_detailController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Output:

```
controller:<DetailViewController: 0xb3e2200> //first item
controller:<DetailViewController: 0xa3d0a00> //second item
//error here, because it attempts to present the view controller at address 0xb3e2200, instead of the second item.
```

Can anyone provide any suggestions as to why this is happening? This only happens in the iPad simulator, but works as intended for the iPhone version for some reason too...?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemed to have stemmed from the fact that the UIModalPresentationStyle for _detailController was FullScreen. I'm not sure if it's an xCode bug, or whether I'm implementing this incorrectly, but once I changed the view to CurrentContext, the error stopped occurring.